# A basis for tensor product

Tags: tensor-products

Let $V , W$ be two vector spaces on a field $K$ and let ${\{v_i\}}_{i = 1}^n$, ${\{w_j\}}_{j = 1}^m$ be two basis, respectively. I want to prove that ${\{v_i \otimes w_j\}}_{(i , j) \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \times \{1 , \ldots , m\}}$ is a basis for $V \otimes W$ (and it shows that $V \otimes W$ is a $(n m)$-dimensional vector space on $K$). I have already proved that, for fixed $(v \otimes w) \in V \otimes W$, there is a sequence ${\{{\nu}_{i j}\}}_{(i , j) \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \times \{1 , \ldots , m\}} \subset K$ such that
$$
v \otimes w = \sum_{(i , j) \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \times \{1 , \ldots , m\}} {\nu}_{i j} (v_i \otimes w_j)\mbox{;}
$$
in fact, ${\nu}_{i j} = {\lambda}_i {\mu}_j$ for all $i = 1 , \ldots , n$ and for all $j = 1 , \ldots , m$, where the sequences ${\{{\lambda}_i\}}_{i = 1}^n$ and ${\{{\mu}_j\}}_{j = 1}^m$ are determinated by the next equalities:
$$
v = \sum_{i = 1}^n {\lambda}_i v_i \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad w = \sum_{j = 1}^m {\mu}_i w_j\mbox{.}
$$
Therefore I only want to prove now that ${\{v_i \otimes w_j\}}_{(i , j) \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \times \{1 , \ldots , m\}}$ forms a linearly independent system of vectors. With the above notation, we can state that
$$
\sum_{(i , j) \in \{1 , \ldots , n\} \times \{1 , \ldots , m\}} {\nu}_{i j} (v_i \otimes w_j) = 0 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n {\lambda}_i v_i\right) \otimes \left(\sum_{j = 1}^m {\mu}_i w_j\right) = 0\mbox{.} \tag{1}
$$
As we know that ${\nu}_{i j} = {\lambda}_i {\mu}_j$, we just need to see that ${\lambda}_i = 0$ for all $i = 1 , \ldots , n$ or ${\mu}_j = 0$ for all $j = 1 , \ldots , m$ and it is followed, as ${\{v_i\}}_{i = 1}^n$ and ${\{w_j\}}_{j = 1}^m$ are basis for $V$ and $W$ respectively, from one of the two next statements:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n {\lambda}_i v_i = 0 \qquad \mbox{ or } \qquad \sum_{j = 1}^m {\mu}_i w_j = 0\mbox{.} \tag{2}
$$
And now I am prepared to make my question: does (1) imply (2)?

Answer (score 1):

Picking up from the hypothesis of (1) you can argue as follows:  Define $\forall k,l: \beta_{kl}:V\times W\to K$ by $\beta_{kl}:=v_k^\ast w_l^\ast$, where $v_k^\ast(v_i)=\delta_{ki}$ and $w_l^\ast(v_j)=\delta_{lj}$. Then $\forall k,l :\beta_{kl}$ is bilinear, and hence by the universal property of tensor products $\forall k,l ,\exists!$ linear $\gamma_{kl}:V\otimes W\to K$ such that $\gamma_{kl}(v_i\otimes w_j)=\delta_{ki}\delta_{lj}$. Applying $\gamma_{kl}$ to the hypothesis of (1) now suffices for linear independency.

By the bilinearity of tensor products, $v=0$ or $w=0$ implies $v\otimes w=0$, thus you seem to be asking about the converse, which is true, but its truth depends on what you are trying to prove. Indeed, once it is established that $\{v_i\otimes w_j\}_{i,j}$ is a basis for $V\otimes W$, if $v=\sum_i \lambda_iv_i\in V\setminus 0$ and $ w=\sum_j \mu_j w_j\in W\setminus 0$, then $\exists i,j: \lambda_i\neq0\neq\mu_j\implies\nu_{ij}\neq0 \implies v\otimes w\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you by your answer although I don't understand very well the definition of ${\beta}_{k l}$.

Comment: Where are defined $v_k^*$ and $w_l^*$?

Comment: $\{v_k^\ast\}_{k=1}^n$ is a basis for $V^\ast$, the so called dual basis (for the dual space), $\delta_{ki}$ is the Dirac delta, so that its value is $1$ (which is the multiplicative identity of your base field $K$) when and only when $k=i$. Similarly for the other one.

Comment: I think that you want yo say Korecker delta instead of Dirac delta, right?

Comment: The name does not really matter as they stand for similar objects but sure.